# Can I set up a CNAME catch-all redirect from one subdomain level to a higher subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, cname, amazon-route53

I have hundreds of subdomains set up for environments in Route53 for AWS that look like this:

```
<appX>.dev.internalurl.us
<appX>.qa.internalurl.us
<appX>.pt.internalurl.us
<appX>.internalurl.us
```

The issue is that our production internal urls are missing the 'prod' env in the url which requires us to add conditionals to all our config scripts, like:

if 'prod.' in url:
   url = url.substring('prod.', '')

What I'd like is:

```
<appX>.prod.internalurl.us to go to <appX>.internalurl.us automatically.
```

EDIT:

I added a CNAME to route prod.internalurl.us to internalurl.us like so:

*.prod.internalurl.us > internalurl.us

but this obviously won't work since I need a capture group on the wildcard! It's ignoring the first "appX" subdomain.

I don't want to have to enter in hundreds of CNAMES,so am looking for a catch-all redirect for one sub-domain level to its parent.

Is there a way to do this with CNAME or does it require running an nginx proxy at prod.internalurl.us to make this work?

Comment: That's interesting question!

Comment: We need to clarify your desired end result.  CNAMEs, or anything else in DNS for that matter, will never change what the browser sends to the server.  foo.example.com CNAME foo.prod.example.com will still cause the *original* hostname (foo.example.com) typed into the browser (or provided in a link, or used with `curl`, etc.) to be sent to the web server in headers.  Can you clarify your purpose?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Anatoly thanks, I didn't see this answer until now. After some fiddling, I edited my question to reflect what I'm really looking for. Still haven't found a solution, but mostly because I've been sidetracked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that may help is simple enough. To find it out let me ask a question. Why do you need this functionality on DNS level?

> What I'd like is:
>
> .prod.internalurl.us to go to .internalurl.us
>   automatically.

CNAME doesn't help with conditional URL rewrite, there is no such logic on that layer. What helps is HTTP layer 301 redirect can be managed via Nginx:

```
server {
  server_name  ~^(?<app>.+)\.prod\.internalurl\.us$;
  return       301 http://$app.internalurl.us$request_uri;
}
```

There is no proxy but HTTP 301 redirect instead.

Comment: Thanks, edited my question with clarifications. What you appear to be saying here is, "no, CNAME can't do that. You'll need a proxy server set up specifically for this use case." Correct?

Comment: I think the point is, you _could_ use CNAME records but you don't need to. If you have catch-all dns setup, you can configure your server to do whatever you want for any subdomains requests and not have to worry about editing your dns all the time.

Comment: @putnamhill unfortunately your comment is absolutely unclear.

Comment: @Anatoly, thanks that does the trick! I didn't need the functionality through DNS.. but thought originally that DNS would be the easiest way. This is certainly easy enough.